# RabbitMQ Binder null x-death within retry loop creating infinite retries before killing consumer

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have a retry loop going with use of the dead letter queue to schedule retries until hitting a limit. The issue I have is the `x-death` header is always coming back null whilst it's clearly aware of the failure as `x-exception-message` and `x-exception-stacktrace` are present.

This is what's happenning in my Spring tests where I use a testcontainers version of rabbit with 3.9-management docker image

Here is an example of Rabbit MQ binder class:

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
@Service
@Slf4j
public class RabbitMqListener {
  
  @Value("${events.retries:10}")
  private long maxRetries;

  @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
  public void process(Event<Map<String, Object>> event,
                      @Header(name = "x-death", required = false) Map<?, ?> death,
                      @Headers Map<?,?> headers,
                      @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long deliveryTag) {
    log.debug("Received event with Id:{} and deliveryTag:{}", event.getId(), deliveryTag);
    log.debug("headers:{}", headers);
    log.debug("x-death header:{}", death);
    if (death != null && death.get("count") != null &&
        Long.valueOf(death.get("count").toString()).compareTo(maxRetries) >= 0) {
      log.error("Max retries reached for event with Id:{}", event.getId());
      throw new ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException("Failed after " + (maxRetries + 1) + " attempts");
    }
    
    try {
      processEvent(event);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Fail to evaluate event with id:" + event.getId(), e);
    }

  }

  private boolean processEvent(Event<Map<String, Object>> event) {
    //redacted - you can trust that in this test case it's throwing an exception
  }

}
```

My config:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
    dynamic: true
  cloud.stream:
    bindings:
      input:
        destination: events
        group: service
        binder: rabbit
        consumer:
          maxAttempts: 1
    rabbit:
      bindings:
        input:
          consumer:
            autoBindDlq: true
            dlqTtl: 1500
            deadLetterExchange:
    default.contentType: application/json
```

And some logs for the test:

```
[INFO] [main] 14:03:58.448 SpringBootMockServletContext - Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
[INFO] [main] 14:03:58.448 TestDispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet ''
[INFO] [main] 14:03:58.471 TestDispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 23 ms
[INFO] [main] 14:03:58.577 CachingConnectionFactory - Attempting to connect to: [localhost:61215]
[INFO] [main] 14:03:58.584 CachingConnectionFactory - Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory.publisher#6b28d4e4:0/SimpleConnection@40941b54 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:61215/, localPort= 61229]
[ERROR] [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:61215] 14:03:58.595 CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - operation not permitted on the default exchange, class-id=50, method-id=20)
[ERROR] [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:61215] 14:03:59.616 CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - operation not permitted on the default exchange, class-id=50, method-id=20)
[ERROR] [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:61215] 14:04:01.633 CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - operation not permitted on the default exchange, class-id=50, method-id=20)
[ERROR] [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:61215] 14:04:05.648 CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - operation not permitted on the default exchange, class-id=50, method-id=20)
[ERROR] [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:61215] 14:04:10.678 CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - operation not permitted on the default exchange, class-id=50, method-id=20)
```

Then several loops of this logging from consuming the message

```
[DEBUG] [events.service-1] 14:04:11.886 RabbitMqListener - Received event with id:foobar and deliveryTag:2
[DEBUG] [events.service-1] 14:04:11.886 RabbitMqListener - headers:{amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=, amqp_deliveryTag=2, amqp_consumerQueue=events.service, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=events.service, x-exception-message=Fail to event with id:foobar, x-original-routingKey=events, amqp_timestamp=Wed Dec 14 14:03:58 GMT 2022, amqp_messageId=4ae864f8-0709-1fdc-b26d-611573474d60, x-original-exchange=events, id=9fe66161-d224-2988-7ddd-337975fec66a, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-QQ85gnjxKZvE5RTYUWJ1hg, sourceData=(Body:'{"id":"foobar","timestamp":1671026638483}' MessageProperties [headers={x-exception-message=Fail to evaluate event with id:foobar, x-original-routingKey=events, x-original-exchange=events, x-exception-stacktrace=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown while invoking RabbitMqListener#process[4 args]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Fail to evaluate event with id:foobar, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[359], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=events, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=events.service, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=events, amqp_timestamp=Wed Dec 14 14:03:58 GMT 2022, amqp_messageId=4ae864f8-0709-1fdc-b26d-611573474d60, id=ca45340c-a895-61c7-2bc5-99b88b6b7e23, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-QQ85gnjxKZvE5RTYUWJ1hg, sourceData=(Body:'{"id":"foobar","timestamp":1671026638483}' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=Wed Dec 14 14:03:58 GMT 2022, messageId=4ae864f8-0709-1fdc-b26d-611573474d60, contentType=application/json, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=events, receivedRoutingKey=events, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-QQ85gnjxKZvE5RTYUWJ1hg, consumerQueue=events.service]), contentType=application/json, timestamp=1671026651701}]
[DEBUG] [events.service-1] 14:04:11.887 RabbitMqListener - x-death header:null
[ERROR] [events.service-1] 14:04:11.889 LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown while invoking RabbitMqListener#process[4 args]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Fail to evaluate event with id:foobar, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[359], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=, amqp_deliveryTag=2, amqp_consumerQueue=events.service, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=events.service, x-exception-message=Fail to evaluate event with id:foobar, x-original-routingKey=events, amqp_timestamp=Wed Dec 14 14:03:58 GMT 2022, amqp_messageId=4ae864f8-0709-1fdc-b26d-611573474d60, x-original-exchange=events, id=9fe66161-d224-2988-7ddd-337975fec66a, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-QQ85gnjxKZvE5RTYUWJ1hg, sourceData=(Body:'{"id":"foobar","timestamp":1671026638483}' MessageProperties [headers={x-exception-message=Fail to evaluate event with id:foobar, x-original-routingKey=events, x-original-exchange=events, x-exception-stacktrace=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown while invoking RabbitMqListener#process[4 args]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Fail to evaluate event with id:foobar, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[359], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=events, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=events.service, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=events, amqp_timestamp=Wed Dec 14 14:03:58 GMT 2022, amqp_messageId=4ae864f8-0709-1fdc-b26d-611573474d60, id=ca45340c-a895-61c7-2bc5-99b88b6b7e23, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-QQ85gnjxKZvE5RTYUWJ1hg, sourceData=(Body:'{"id":"foobar","timestamp":1671026638483}' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=Wed Dec 14 14:03:58 GMT 2022, messageId=4ae864f8-0709-1fdc-b26d-611573474d60, contentType=application/json, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=events, receivedRoutingKey=events, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-QQ85gnjxKZvE5RTYUWJ1hg, consumerQueue=events.service]), contentType=application/json, timestamp=1671026651701}]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:64)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$800(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:322)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:285)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1630)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1537)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1528)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1472)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:977)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:923)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1298)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1204)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Fail to evaluate event with id:foobar
    at com.foo.bar.listener.RabbitMqListener.processEvent(RabbitMqListener.java:99)
    at com.foo.bar.listener.RabbitMqListener.process(RabbitMqListener.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: [no body]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:780)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:639)
    at com.foo.bar.client.ClientImpl.readObject(ClientImpl.java:46)
    at com.foo.bar.client.ClientImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e4db9dde.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(CacheInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:421)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:346)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    ... 35 more
}, timestamp=Wed Dec 14 14:03:58 GMT 2022, messageId=4ae864f8-0709-1fdc-b26d-611573474d60, contentType=application/json, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=events.service, deliveryTag=3, consumerTag=amq.ctag-QQ85gnjxKZvE5RTYUWJ1hg, consumerQueue=events.service]), contentType=application/json, x-exception-stacktrace=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown while invoking RabbitMqListener#process[4 args]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Fail to evaluate event with id:foobar, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[359], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=events, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=events.service, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=events, amqp_timestamp=Wed Dec 14 14:03:58 GMT 2022, amqp_messageId=4ae864f8-0709-1fdc-b26d-611573474d60, id=ca45340c-a895-61c7-2bc5-99b88b6b7e23, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-QQ85gnjxKZvE5RTYUWJ1hg, sourceData=(Body:'{"id":"foobar","timestamp":1671026638483}' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=Wed Dec 14 14:03:58 GMT 2022, messageId=4ae864f8-0709-1fdc-b26d-611573474d60, contentType=application/json, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=events, receivedRoutingKey=events, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-QQ85gnjxKZvE5RTYUWJ1hg, consumerQueue=events.service]), contentType=application/json, timestamp=1671026651701}]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:64)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$800(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:322)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:285)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1630)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1537)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1528)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1472)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:977)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:923)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1298)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1204)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Failed to evaluate event with id:foobar
    at com.foo.bar.listener.RabbitMqListener.processEvent(RabbitMqListener.java:99)
    at com.foo.bar.listener.RabbitMqListener.process(RabbitMqListener.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: [no body]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:780)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:639)
    at com.foo.bar.client.ClientImpl.readObject(ClientImpl.java:46)
    at com.foo.bar.client.ClientImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e4db9dde.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(CacheInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:421)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:346)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    ... 35 more
```

We get several repeats of this loop before

```
[ERROR] [events.service-1] 14:04:11.951 SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer thread error, thread abort.
[ERROR] [events.service-1] 14:04:11.954 SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Stopping container from aborted consumer
[INFO] [events.service-1] 14:04:11.954 SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Waiting for workers to finish.
[INFO] [events.service-1] 14:04:11.954 SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Successfully waited for workers to finish.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x-death` header is set by the broker, when it (the broker) routes a rejected message to the DLQ; by default, instead of rejecting a message, the binder republishes to the DLQ with additional information such as exception (which is not available when the broker does the routing).

To use broker routing instead, set `republishToDlq` to `false`.

Comment: This managed to solve the issue of the null x-death header thank you.